# Meteor.js filter collections by value in field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, collections, meteor

Currently in meteor.js im trying to figure out how to return all collections with a field containing a particular value:

```js
Posts.insert({
  tags: ['test', 'test1', 'test2'],
  categories: ['test', 'planning'],
  article: {
    title: 'Lorem ipsum dollar sum import',
    content: 'Lorem balck solo su, bella hun sillo.',
    author: 'test'
  },
  comments: [{title: 'test', 'content': 'hello world'},],
});
```

So, for instance in the context of filtering posts by category how can I return all the collections with the categories array containing a string matching 'test' or 'planning' and exclude those that don't contain that string in the array?

This is for a simple blog app I have been working on, also if there is a more efficient way of storing posts and associated information please let me know that world be awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [$in](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/operator/query/in/) operator. For example:

```js
Posts.find({categories: {$in: ['test', 'planning']}});
```

Would find all posts where `categories` has at least one element matching either `'test'` or `'planning'`.